# Popen with keyword cwd cause windows error 2

Tags: python, windows

I have a piece of code that takes in a user-provided path to an executable or batch file. I split the path to get the filename and path (tail and head), and use the head as the current working directory for the new process. If the path does not contain directories, it works fine. However, I get the following error if it does:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Example code:

```
def poop(self, path_to_program):
    head, tail = path.split(path_to_program)
    if(head.startswith('"')):
        head = head.strip('"')

    if(tail.endswith('"')):
        tail = tail.strip('"')                

    if(head<>''):
        p = Popen(tail, cwd=head, shell=False)
    else:
        p = Popen(tail)
```

If `path_to_program` is not split and passed directly to Popen, it works fine.

Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: This is probably the first time I see someone using the `<>` operator in the wild – reminds me of my Pascal days. :)  Note that this operator is depcreated and has been removed in Python 3.x (in favour of `!=`).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I vaguely remember reading somewhere that `<>` was the operator for not equals. I had no clue it had been deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to cwd.

What's happening is that `cwd` is the directory where the executable is executed.  It is **NOT** the directory where subprocess looks for the executable.  What you might want is:

```
p = Popen(path_to_program, cwd=head, shell=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) for Popen says this about the cwd argument:

> Note that this directory is not considered when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path relative to `cwd`.

So I think in the case where `head` is not the empty string, you would need to call Popen as:

```
p = Popen(path_to_program, cwd=head, shell=False)
```